# Python while loop that adds the user inputs and then creates an average

Tags: python, while-loop

> "For this task you have the chance to show what you’ve learned about
> implementing repetition in code. You are required to create a program
> that uses the while loop structure.
>
> Write a program that always asks the user to enter a number. When the
> user enters the negative number -1, the program should stop requesting
> the user to enter a number. The program must then calculate the
> average of the numbers entered excluding the -1.
>
> Make use of the while loop repetition structure to implement the
> program."

I got this far and am not sure how to list the input numbers on an infinite range??

```
#Ask the user to pick a number
print("Pick a number")
attempt = 1
answer =

int(input("Answer: ")), [],0


#While the answer does not equals -1 pick another number
while answer != -1:
print("Pick another number.")
        # increase the attempt number
        attempt += 1
        print("Attempt number " + (str(attempt)))
        # increase the answer total
        answer=[]
        for n in range(attempt):
          answer.append(answer)
        print("Answer total " + (str(answer)))
        
        # ask the user again for an input
        answer = int(input("Answer: "))
        if answer==-1:
          print ("The total averge of your answers is" + sum(answer))
```

Comment: The instructions only say to use `while`, so why do you have `for n in range()`? And what did you expect to happen by appending a list to itself?

Answer (score 0):

The basic things you want to keep track of are: the running sum (an integer) and the total number of attempts (also an integer). I have reordered your code to track these two, and then when the user inputs -1 we calculate the average by dividing the running sum by the number of attempts.

```
#Ask the user to pick a number
print("Pick a number")
num_attempt = 0
answer = 0
answer_sum = 0

# While the answer does not equals -1 pick another number
while answer != -1:
    
    
    # ask the user again for an input
    answer = int(input("Answer: "))
    
    if answer == -1:
        print ("The total average of your answers is " + str(answer_sum / num_attempt))
        break

    # increase the attempt number
    num_attempt += 1

    print("Attempt number " + (str(num_attempt)))
    
    # increase the answer total
    answer_sum += answer
    print("Answer total " + (str(answer_sum)))
    print("Pick another number.")
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are considering the situation wrongly by restating the answer array to an empty one at each iteration. What you need to do is that you keep track of the answers with that array, because you will need them afterward to calculate the average. Moreover, make sure to save at each iteration the value entered by the user, so that you can compare it with -1 (in your code, you are comparing the array to -1 which is absurd).

take a look at this code, it may help.

```
 #Ask the user to pick a number
 print("Pick a number")
 attempt = 1
 answer = []

 # a variable to keep track of the values that the user give
 currentValue = int(input("Answer: "))
 # append this variable to the array of the answers
 answer.append(currentValue)

 #While the answer does not equals -1 pick another number
 while currentValue != -1:
    print("Pick another number.")
    # increase the attempt number
    attempt += 1
    print("Attempt number " + (str(attempt)))

    # ask the user again for an input
    currentValue = int(input("Answer: "))

    # if the user wants to quit, output the result
    if currentValue ==-1:
       print ("The total averge of your answers is" , sum(answer) / 
       len(answer))

    # else, just append the value to our array of values
    else:
       answer.append(currentValue)
```